# Getting incorrect readings from image

Tags: c++, pixel, sdl-image

I have made a image of 3x3 with all squares black (0,0,0) unless the corners...
Where I have a red, green, blue and white pixel, as illustrated below:

```
R, 0, G
0, 0, 0
B, 0, W
```

Which should be placed as `R, 0, G, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, W` in the pixeldata array if I understood it correctly.
The problem I'm having is that what is printed out is:

```
[255, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 255] [0, 0, 255] [255, 0, 0]
```

Here is my code:

```
Uint32 GetPixel(SDL_Surface *img, int x, int y) {
    //Convert the pixels to 32 bit
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*)img->pixels;

    //Get the requested pixel
    Uint32 offsetY = y * img->w;
    Uint32 offsetPixel = offsetY + x;
    Uint32 pixel = pixels[offsetPixel];

    return pixel;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Surface *img = IMG_Load("Images/Colors.png");
    vector <Uint32> pixels;

    SDL_LockSurface(img);

    for (int y = 0; y < img->h; y++) {
        Uint8 r, g, b;
        Uint32 pixel;
        for (int x = 0; x < img->w; x++) {
            pixel = GetPixel(img, x, y);

            SDL_GetRGB(pixel, img->format, &r, &g, &b);
            printf("[%u, %u, %u]\t", r, g, b);
            pixels.push_back(pixel);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    SDL_UnlockSurface(img);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: What I expected:

```
[255, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0]   [0, 255, 0]
[0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 255] [0, 0, 0]   [255, 255, 255]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within your `GetPixel` function. Try something like this instead:

```
Uint32 GetPixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;
    return *(Uint32*)p;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but can you specify what was going wrong? Was I accessing the wrong memory?

Comment: A more complete/correct version: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Pixel_Access . Basically the problem is that you're assuming 2 things that may not be neccessarily true: 1) the line pitch == img->w * bpp - see this: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/518067-sdl-what-is-pitch/ ; 2) you have 32-bit encoding for pixels (in my test I was dealing with a 3bpp png file)